# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. when I import model

Tags: python, django, django-models, anaconda

I am new python also Django. I know the same issue is posted in this forum. but still, can't figure it out.  created a model and need to import in my views.py file so I can render my data.

this is my views.py

```
from  first_app.models import Topic, webpage, AccessRecord 
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# from django.apps import AppConfig

    # Create your views here.
    def index(request): 
        webpage_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
        date_dict = {'acess_records': webpage_list}
        return render(request, 'first_app/index.html')
```

and it showed me this error

```
PS E:\python\firstp\first_project> python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000024518AB58C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\python\firstp\first_project\first_app\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I tried many things from previous post but still no progress. 
[github repository](https://github.com/sagar290/python_practice)

Comment: You forget to register your app, by adding it inside `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu actually forget to register your app, go to `settings.py`, you will see an list named `INSTALLED_APPS`, add the name of your app `first_app`.
[More info can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #names,
    'first_app',
]
```

Comment: @pclover all the apps that you create must be registered inside INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: I did still showing me raise `AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`.

Comment: Here is my [github repository](https://github.com/sagar290/python_practice) you can check. :(

Comment: @pclover I took a look at your settings file. Why do you have [`first_app.urls`](https://github.com/sagar290/python_practice/blob/master/first_project/settings.py#L41) included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list? Could be the reason for the error. Remove this line and try again.

Comment: you're right @xyres , I just saw it in his repository, remove first_app.urls. it's not an app

Comment: because in urls.py I use `url(r'^first_app/', include('first_app.urls')) ` and if I am not added this also throws me an error. after adding this it was working fine.

Comment: No need.  by adding the `app_name` inside INSTALLED_APPS, Django will find your `app.urls` well

Comment: but dont know after removing this its working now. :D thanks  @Lemayzeur

Comment: You're welcome @pclover, as I said : **all the apps that you create must be registered inside `INSTALLED_APPS`**